# How can I get v-pagination to start with a specific page that user choose (instead of starting from page 1)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm accessing data from database, and I am using v-pagination component (with vuetify) to separate the data. However, I have users that would like to start right away with page 10, let's say, everytime they route to that component.

My question is, is there a way that I can start the v-pagination component from index 10, or 11, or whatever (depends on an integer input) ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `v-model` value to set the current selected page.

```
    <v-pagination
      v-model="page"
      :circle="circle"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :length="length"
      :next-icon="nextIcon"
      :prev-icon="prevIcon"
      :page="page"
      :total-visible="totalVisible"
    ></v-pagination>
```

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        page: 2, // current page
        // ....
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

[the vuetify page documents](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations/)